# Grails - Get index of one-to-many list based relation in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, grails, mapping, grails-orm

I have a model which contains multiple one-to-many relationships. One of them is a class `PageList` which contains multiple `HeaderEntries`. Each `HeaderEntry` is used to store information about the header of one column that all `Pages` in the `PageList` have in common. 
Since the `HeaderEntries` of the pages have a particular order which is used in future operations, this order of the `HeaderEntries` is important and shall be persisted.

Since `HeaderEntries` can be deleted from the `Header`, I don't want to add a attribute `idx` to each `HeaderEntry` and update it on all `HeaderEntries` 'by hand', if one of them is deleted or a new one is added.

Therefor i used the following code

```
List<HeaderEntry> header
static hasMany = [header: HeaderEntry]
```

on the side of the `PageList`, and

```
static belongsTo = [pagelist: PageList]
```

on the side of the `HeaderEntry`.

I used `MySQL` in the past and everything worked fine since an attribute `header_idx` was added to the db for each `HeaderEntry` which was updated automatically when an `HeaderEntry` was added or removed. When a `HeaderEntry` was loaded later on, the `header` could be accessed as a list of correctly sorted `HeaderEntries` where the position of a `HeaderEntry` that was saved with another object could be easily determined by the use of `indexOf` on the list `header`.

Due to performance issues I want to change the db to `MongoDB` but I am unable to reproduce the described behavior. With the code avove, no attribute `header_idx` is generated so that lists loose their order. If I use

```
static embedded = ['header']
```

I would have a lot of duplicate entries in the db since the same `HeaderEntries` are referenced from many objects. Or is this the way to go in document orientated dbs? In addition i am unable to use `indexOf` since a `HeaderEntry` stored by a different object than the `PageList` is interpreted as a different object as the corresponding `HeaderEntry` in `header`.

The described behavior not only applies to the `PageList <-> Header` relationship, but many others.